# android multiple (rotated) seekbars layout

Tags: android, rotation, seekbar

my question is about multiple rotated seekbars. The idea I came up with is to make a square of seekbars, value 0 to 5, where value 5 of seekbar1 touches value 0 of seekbar2 and so on. Found adroid:rotation="-90" but i have problems getting them in a nice and clean layout wich also can be started with empty values on some clicklistener.
I asume it's got more to do with rotate properties of the seekbars? Can't find though. Tried both linear and relativeLayout

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar) where the seekbars are vertical(probably that's what you want) in nature and you can apply them multiple times to achieve it.